# Why Wordpress cron not running without the interaction with the website?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am using the Cron job in my WordPress plugin but the cron does not run without the user interaction with the WordPress website. Is there any solution that I can run my cron perfectly after the 5 minutes without failure.

Comment: Are you using [`wp_cron()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) or just plain old cron? If you're using `wp_cron()` then it won't run unless you interact with the site.

Comment: @dingo_d can you please suggest me any solution or example

Comment: Try searching here on SO. Nothing comes to mind off the top of my head atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your script at schedule action

```
wp_schedule_single_event(time(),'your_function_name',array('arguments'));
```

Then the function will run if you will access that page.

If you want to run your cron job at some interval of time then try to setup your job from cpanel and in command prompt write the complete path to this function access.

```
class Example_cron {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->your_function_name();
    }
    function your_function_name() {
        // write your script here 
    }
}
$objct = new Example_cron();
```

Setup your cron path to this file.It will Run automatically.

Command to setup cron:

```
php/usr/bin <file path>// example opt/lammp/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/<your plugin name>/<your fine name>
```

Thanks